# cmd equivalent of std::string::find_first:of

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, substring

C++, Java, JavaScript, and possibly other programming languages all have a string function that searches a string for *any* character in a specified string pattern. For example, C++'s [`std::string::find_first_of`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/find_first_of/) works like this:

```
std::cout << "Vowel found in : " << "Search me for vowels".find_first_of("aeiou") << std::endl;
// should print "Vowel found in : 1".
```

Is there any equivalent of that in CMD? I tried searching "dos string functions" but couldn't seem to find anything.

Comment: I have some code at work that finds the position of string within another string. I will post it on Monday.

Comment: You do realize that the Windows batch language was never intended for general-purpose programming?  It is of course *possible* to do this sort of thing, but there's no built-in function library to make it easy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly, you don't explain *why* the output is "1" or what "1" signifies.

```
set "string=Search me for vowels"
echo %string%|findstr /i "a e i o u" >nul
echo %errorlevel%
```

should show `errorlevel` as 0 for "found" and 1 for "not found".

the string is `echo`ed as input to `findstr`.

The `/i` makes the comparison case-insensitive.

the `>nul` suppresses output

the `"a e i o u"` means "search for one of these strings" (space-separated, 5 strings to locate)

Of course, this is a trivial example. `findstr /?` from the prompt or searching examples on SO would give you more tricks of the trade.

Comment: This only tells you if the string contains the character. To replicate find_first_of you want to find the character position

Comment: Did you see the link I posted in the question?

Answer (score 2):

There is no direct way, but you can write your own fairly easily.

To search for one character

```
@echo off
call :charposition "Search me for vowels" a pos
echo Found a at position %pos%

goto :eof
:charposition
set "string_search=%~1"
set /a char_pos=0
:charcheck
IF %string_search:~0,1%==%2 (
endlocal & set "%3=%char_pos%"
goto :eof
)
set "string_search=%string_search:~1%"
IF "%string_search%"=="" (
set "%3=Not Found"
goto :eof
)
set /a char_pos+=1
goto :charcheck
```

For multiple characters:

```
@echo off
call :charposition "Search me for vowels" aeiou pos
echo Found vowel at position %pos%

goto :eof
:charposition
set "string_search=%~1"
set /a char_pos=0
:charcheck
echo %2|find "%string_search:~0,1%">nul
IF %errorlevel%==0 (
endlocal & set "%3=%char_pos%"
goto :eof
)
set "string_search=%string_search:~1%"
IF "%string_search%"=="" (
set "%3=Not Found"
goto :eof
)
set /a char_pos+=1
goto :charcheck
```

See http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-substring.html for an explanation of the syntax for extracting substrings. As given, these are case sensitive.